# html, javascript - popup window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, popup

i have popup-window in my script. I use window.open, but almost all browsers block this kind of windows. So i wanna change it to another popup, which include php-script. I saw it at another sites. As i understand, they use ajax. Could you provide for me some more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the solution provided by [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: The thickbox page has been removed. Any other alternative...??

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a div (or other element) with the aspect you want, adding it the following extra CSS:

```
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px; // changeable
  left: 100px; // changeable
}
```

Then you use JavaScript to change the CSS making the div visible, and add the XHTML response from AJAX to its `innerHTML`.

I'd recommend using jQuery or other easy-to-use framework if you're used to JavaScript / AJAX.